# Pass selected variables to form with URL

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have this code here:

```
<form action="http://192.168.10.253:82/montim/montime-bcp/montime/vendosja-porosise/listasearch.php?kategoria=kategoria" method="post">
<select name="kategoria">
  <option value="klienti">Klienti</option>
  <option value="id">ID</option>
</select> 
</form>
```

So, i need to pass to kategoria value the selected option... how can i do that?
Thanks..

Comment: ?kategoria=kategoria so you want to use GET or POST ?

Comment: You need to add a `submit` button to your form.

Comment: Barmar yes, i jut posted this sample code, but my form is bigger...
Christian, post would be better..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a method of `GET`, your form data will be sent in the URL:

```
<form action="http://192.168.10.253:82/montim/montime-bcp/montime/vendosja-porosise/listasearch.php" method="get">
    <select name="kategoria">
      <option value="klienti">Klienti</option>
      <option value="id">ID</option>
    </select> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly :)
thanks, i'm accepting in a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to get selected value using below syntax

It gets value attribute

```
$('select').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Form:

```
<form action="http://192.168.10.253:82/montim/montime-bcp/montime/vendosja-porosise/listasearch.php" method="post">
    <select name="kategoria">
      <option value="klienti">Klienti</option>
      <option value="id">ID</option>
    </select> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Your listasearch.php

```
<?php $kategoria = $_POST['kategoria']; echo $kategoria; ?>
```

If you want method get (with ?kategoria=kategoria):

```
<form action="http://192.168.10.253:82/montim/montime-bcp/montime/vendosja-porosise/listasearch.php" method="get">
    <select name="kategoria">
      <option value="klienti">Klienti</option>
      <option value="id">ID</option>
    </select> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Your listasearch.php

```
<?php $kategoria = $_GET['kategoria']; echo $kategoria; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the 'method' attribute to "GET" instead of "POST"

```
<form action="yoururl" method="GET">
....
</form>
```

The difference is that GET pass the values on the URL, and POST in the headers.
You can read more information here -> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp